# Angular 2 multiple errors such as Template parse errors and Can't bind to

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am new to AG2.Just started for 1 day. I tried some online tutorial and follow their coding exactly but get error.

```
directives: [favour_component]  // only this line of coding is marked RED
```

Then from the chrome console, the error is

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:Can't bind to 'isfavour' since it isn't a known property of 'favours'.
```

May I know whats wrong with my coding?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {favour_component} from './favour.component'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
          <favours [isfavour]="post.isfavour"></favours>
  `,
  directives: [favour_component]
})
export class AppComponent { 
post={
  title:"title",
  isfavour:true
}
}
```

**favour.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'favours',
template: `
        <i 
        class="glyphicon"
        [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!favour"[class.glyphicon-star]="favour" (click)="onClick()">
        </i>
`
})
export class favour_component { 
@Input() isfavour=false;
onClick(){
this.isfavour=!this.isfavour;
}
}
```

Its a very simple tutorial just like SOF mark as favourite question (star) . The screenshot is their coding.

[image]

I search on SOF, they have some similar error but the scenario is totally different, i cant understand their coding at all. Hence i post it here.

Comment: add `favour_component` in your `AppModule`'s NgModule `declarations`

Comment: @PankajParkar hi Pankaj, any example? I just touch AG2 today, i not sure how to do that?

Comment: does your tutorial prompt you to go grab the angular quickstart package.json, and sytemjs.config.js files? it looks like you are using a different version of angular than the tutorial that you are following, which will cause all sorts of problems. A tip off is that your component import is `@angular/core` while your tutorial is 'angular2/core' I would strongly recommend just following the quickstart [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) their docs are rich and will quickly get you a running basic angular 2 application

Comment: @gosulove checkout the answer which I've added. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bean0341 thx! you are totally right. angular.io didn't update their website, i download their quickstart and guess what? its still angular but not angular2 !!!  .

Comment: @gosulove np man, just a word of advice, you might as well start your update to RC.6, angular2 is changing drastically with every new RC. Keeping up with the latest and greatest is a necessity to avoiding random deprecation errors in the future. GL and enjoy angular2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rc5` if you wanted to use any directive or pipe or other component on view, it should be declared in `AppModule`(NgModule) declaration property

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, favour_component ], //Pipes, Components, Directives belongs here
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Thereafter you had a mistake in your template binding change `favour` to `isfavour`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'favours',
  template: `
      <i class="glyphicon"
         [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isfavour" 
         [class.glyphicon-star]="isfavour" 
         (click)="onClick()">{{isfavour}}
      </i>
    `
})
export class favour_component { 

 //....

}
```

Here is [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5S8Q1mcNjDBLZrCrFOzX?p=preview) in action